# $Recycle Bin on c: drive

Tags: windows

After installing the Windows 10 fall update 2018 my c: drive is somehow nearly full.  I installed a file visualization program and it indicates that I have 491 GB of files in it.  How do I delete them and is it safe to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We used to be able to rely on Disk Cleanup; alas, [no more in the latest Windows marque](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2018/08/30/9205/), which was [pulled from circulation after it was first  released](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-pulls-windows-10-october-update-version-1809/).

Instead, we have the “[Free Up Space](https://www.howtogeek.com/348635/use-windows-10s-new-free-up-space-tool-to-clean-up-your-hard-drive/)” tool, at **Settings | System | Storage | Free Up Space** .

If that does not purge an adequate amount of space, (and since Microsoft stated "Any files that you have not used, in the last 30 days, will be eligible for dehydration when your device runs low on free space. Storage Sense will only dehydrate files until there’s enough space freed for Windows to run smoothly,"[1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2018/08/30/9205/) you may wish to be more aggressive than their clean-up algorithm  provides), I'd look at the Open Source [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think the recycle bin had a corrupted file in it or something.  I have a program installed on my computer called "Windows 10 Manager" by Yamicsoft ( https://yamicsoft.com/windows10manager/product.html ).  In it is a "Repair Center" and one of the repairs is an analysis to make sure all necessary components and registry items are healthy and still there.If not, it fixes it automatically.  I ran that and voila', my space went back to normal (about 60% of my 1 TB drive).  That has saved me more than a few times.  It was worth the $29.95 I paid for it! Thanks!